# Why @JsonUnwrapped gets ignored when property's class uses converter of @JsonSerialize?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

Here is a working example (I use latest `2.9.5` Jackson version).

```
public class RootClass {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    public NestedClass nested = new NestedClass();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        RootClass obj = new RootClass();
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj));
    }
}

@JsonSerialize(converter = NestedClassConverter.class)
class NestedClass {
    public String foo = "fooVal";
    public String bar = "barVal";
}

class NestedClassWrapper {
    private NestedClass wrapped;

    public NestedClassWrapper(NestedClass wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return wrapped.foo;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return wrapped.bar;
    }
}

class NestedClassConverter extends StdConverter<NestedClass, NestedClassWrapper> {

    @Override
    public NestedClassWrapper convert(NestedClass value) {
        return new NestedClassWrapper(value);
    }
}
```

If I remove `@JsonSerialize` from `NestedClass` it works as expected and produces `{"foo":"fooVal","bar":"barVal"}`.
But if the converter is used, the nested field does not get "unwrapped" and I get: `{"nested":{"bar":"barVal","foo":"fooVal"}}`.

How can I get an expected unwrapped result still using a `converter`?

Update:
In debugger (`UnwrappingBeanPropertyWriter.class`) I can see that in case of using converter, `_findAndAddDynamic` returns `StdDelegationSerializer`  instead of `UnwrappingBeanSerializer`. Is it a bug or expected behaviour? Any workaround?

Comment: Why do you want an own Converter if jackson already serializes the class as you expect? I do not understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @Heri This is just an example. I want to use a converter for class and also to be able to unwrap converted value as expected. Actually I convert default Log4j2 `LogEvent` to a more suitable object for my project. You can observe the same approach on `log4j2-logstash-jsonevent-layout` project on GitHub.